# UML alternatives in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, uml

I know that visual studio 2017 does not support UML anymore. Can class diagrams fully replace UML and if not what are alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Class diagrams are part of UML. They can't replace it. (see [uml-diagrams.org: Classification of UML 2.5 Diagrams](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-25-diagrams.html)). For the list of Visual Studio alternatives see [Wikipedia: List of UML tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools)